# How to change value of 'Read timeout' of Eclipse's Update Manager?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, equinox

How to change value of 'Read timeout' of Eclipse's Update Manager?

I have slow internet connection and I cannot install any plugin, because Eclipse's Update manager throws me exception:

```
Transfer Exception

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:127)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Frank mentioned you can set the timeout options in the eclipse.ini, here's the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).

"use -DpropName=propValue as a VM argument to the Java VM, set the desired property in the config.ini file in the appropriate configuration area"

I set the following to get round my timeout issue:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=3000
```

Comment: Are these values in milliseconds? If so 3000 doesn't seem a lot - maybe 30000 or 60000 would be better?

Answer (score 14):

I got the error a lot with version 3.6, but adding the following line to the eclipse.ini helped me a lot:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000
```

Add it right after the line with
-vmargs

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get around this would be to download the `.jar` file of the plug-in you're trying to install and perform an offline installation.

**Edit:** I tried to find a link to a how-to, but `eclipse.org` kept timing out on me.

Comment: I used this aproach, but now Eclipse trying to update itself, after calculating requirements for new plugin. And the same old song: 'Read timed out'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you were getting these timeout problems during the rollout of 3.5.1.  Eclipse.org had several server and mirroring issues during this time, and this caused manhy people to experience timeouts when trying to update.

In the future, when you see problems like this, you can try installing from a specific mirror.  I find that installing from here tends to work well even when Eclipse.org is not:

http://eclipse.unixheads.org/

Comment: Thanx for the link. I get timeout on any plugin that is about 4MB and more.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is not the cause, it's just the symptom, there might be "zombie" entries
in the update sites.

Like:

[image: update sites with zombie entries]

After removing those with empty "name" column 
it should work (faster).