# unable to install google app engine plugin for eclipse(indigo)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin, installation, gae-eclipse-plugin

when i try to install google app engine plugin for eclipse it keeps giving below error message at about 47%

"installing software has encountered a problem. An error occured while collecting items to be installed"

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.3.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.rpc_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.appsmarketplace_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.core_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer_2.4.0.r37x201108271303.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.UiBinder_2.4.0.r37x201108271303.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gpe_2.4.0.r37x201108290223.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.ie_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.super_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.webkit_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_2_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_2.ie_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_2.webkit_2.4.0.r37x201108271255.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.subclipse_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.login_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven.e37_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e37_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.core_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.r37v201108301710.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.core_1.1.0.r37x201108271211.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at  dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.core.databinding_1.1.0.r37x201108271211.jar.
Read timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the work around :

1. Separately download the jar files for which read timeout is hapenning.
   In this case download 
   `com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.3_2.0.3.v201002191036.jar`.
   `com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.3_1.3.3.v201004231111.jar`.

   Using above url.
   Note: both jars are above 80MB and takes a while for download.
2. Copy the jars to plugin folder of eclipse
3. Resume plugin installation once again.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting time outs when downloading. Are there some issues with proxy or firewalls?
There could be a heavy load on your internet connection at the moment, so the best option would be to try again at a later time.

If none of that helps, then you could try to change the timeout setting in the eclipse.ini file;

> -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=3000
>
> -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=3000

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489149/how-to-change-value-of-read-timeout-of-eclipses-update-manager)