# How can I update Maven Index manually?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have this problem:

When I start Eclipse **(Indigo Service Release 1 with Maven Integration for Eclipse)** it's trying to download a file from Maven Repositories :

```
repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
```

It reaches about 10-20% (this takes loooong) and then apparently it gives up:

```
02.05.12 08:47:36 MESZ: Updating index central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
02.05.12 09:09:25 MESZ: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

Now I tried to download this gz-file manually because I thought, the download hits any timeout within Eclipse. Now I have another two problems:

1. The direct download of the 48,7 MB-gz-file canceled after 9,6 MB. I have no clue why.
2. If I'd be able to download the gz-file, I don't know how to "put it into" Eclipse/Maven or tell Maven to use the file on my PC and not the repository repo1.maven.org.

Any helpful ideas or answers?

Comment: First i would recommend to use a repository manager and not directly maven central. Than your eclipse will use the index of the internal repository which is of course faster.

Comment: this 'broken' index download comes and goes. Try again often helps.
There is also a view (Window -> Show View -> Maven Repositories) where you can re-try or define repos

Comment: By the way, for [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html) 8 users the answer seems to be: *Preferences* (or Options) > *Java* (tab) > *Maven* (tab) > *Categories: Index* (list item) > *Index Now* button.

Answer (score 10):

1. Delete the cache from `.m2/repository/.cache/m2e`.
2. Open your eclipse
3. Menu Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Update Settings

Eclipse will download it again, should work now.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change the timeout settings like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489149/how-to-change-value-of-read-timeout-of-eclipses-update-manager). I do not know which setting is responsible for the repository index update, you have to try a bit...

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=60000
```

You should consider to disable the index update on startup (disable: `Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository index updates on startup`) and only update manually in the Maven Repositories View using the context menu on the central repository.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that may be a little bit complicated but it worked for me:

- First I used *wget -c* to download nexus-maven-repository-index.gz; took me about 10 retries and an hour; you may use any download manager you like
- Second, installed Fiddler
- Then updated `<proxy>` configuration in local maven *settings.xml* with Fiddler details
- Enabled breakpoints in Fiddler
- When Eclipse asked for nexus-maven-repository-index.gz used a Fiddler feature to substitute a response with a downloaded file

Answer (score 2):

A more drastic way: delete the whole .metadata folder. Later import projects from their place or checkout them from the svn(if you use some). This is not much more complicated, but it helped. the problem is that we don't really know, what metadata are broken, so the natural next step is to delete all of them. I think, it is the deepest possible cleaning before reinstallation of Eclipse + plugins.